# call method problem in solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have simple contract and it has a function to call ERC20 token contract:

```
function _approve(uint256 amount, address to) external payable returns (bool){
        (bool ok,) =
         linkTokenAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address, uint256)",to ,amount));
         return ok;
    }
```

But when i call this function, it reverts. what is the problem?

this is a tx details [you can check](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x57740ae90121890b5616295ea6d10efd3dd636c672e587140849b18909357e2a)

Answer (score 1):

> But when i call this function, it reverts. what is the problem?

The issue is the signature argument of the `abi.encodeWithSignature` function call is incorrect. The proper signature is `approve(address,uint256)` (notice there is no space after the comma).

You can check the solidity docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#function-selector) where they document how to properly generate the signature. The solidity by example site also has a tutorial displaying this [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/).

Comment: Would you edit my function that i i can see how?

Comment: Hi,just remove space and test it,like below:         linkTokenAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address,uint256)",to,amount));

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesn't work. here is transaction hash:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xf5ab2bdf9dd387d4be7e2ee341aff96a0b544133784f722d23832538de94d89f

Comment: The transactions you are providing don't call the function which you are asking about in the original post. You can check the parity traces and see the function calls don't match. I'd recommend you publish the source before asking any more.